# Android - Intent data after AsyncTask

Tags: android, server, android-asynctask

Server connection is working on background (AsyncTask), and server response JSON.
I want to send data from server to other Activity, but it is not working.
I have tried to solve this but nothing work. How I can solve this?
My code is below:

```
public class LoginRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String errorMsg = LOGIN_ERROR;
    String builder;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        JSONObject requestJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {

            requestJsonObject.put("email", userEmail);
            requestJsonObject.put("password", userPassword);
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                BASE_URL,
                requestJsonObject,
                response -> {
                    errorMsg = LOGIN_SUCCESS;
                    Log.d(TAG, "response = " + response);
                    builder = response.toString();
                },
                error -> errorMsg = LOGIN_ERROR
        );

        requestQueue.add(request);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        if (errorMsg.equals(LOGIN_ERROR)) {

            textViewError.setText(R.string.login_failure);
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Send data from server to UserMainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserMainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("serverMessage", builder);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing super.onPostExecute(s);

Comment: No don't remove `super.onPostExecute(s)` as @Shayan said.

Comment: What you are doing is not wrong. Post your json response in shortest manner and also show us how you are handling the passed variable in `UserMainActivity`.

Comment: @ZankrutParmar I change the JSON data from server to String at response Listener, and get the data in UserMainActivity as Intent dataIntent = getIntent();
        serverMessage = dataIntent.getStringExtra(SERVER_MESSAGE);

Comment: serverMessage is just String variable.

Comment: when I try to sending data at onPostExecute, I guess data from doInBackground is not updated yet, so cannot read in onPostExecute method

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your activity context to your asyncTask and start Activity from that context

Your AsyncTask should look like this

```
private class LoginRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


    Context context;
    LoginRequest(Context context)
    {
        this.context=context;
    }


    String builder;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        //your code here

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) { 

        //your code here

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("serverMessage", builder);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Call this asyncTask like this

```
    LoginRequest asyncTaskForceUpdate=new LoginRequest(this);
    asyncTaskForceUpdate.execute();
```

Comment: how about flag to check login is success or not?
At response Listener, I change errorMsg variable to SUCCESS, and error Listener, I change errorMsg variable to FAIL, but at Method onPostExecute, there is an error looks like Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code as below:

```
public class LoginRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String errorMsg = "ERROR";
    String builder = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        JSONObject requestJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {

            requestJsonObject.put("email", userEmail);
            requestJsonObject.put("password", userPassword);
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                BASE_URL,
                requestJsonObject,
                response -> {
                    errorMsg = "SUCCESS";
                    Log.d(TAG, "response = " + response);
                    builder = response.toString();
                },
                error -> errorMsg = "ERROR"
        );

        requestQueue.add(request);
        return errorMsg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        if (s.equals("ERROR")) {

            textViewError.setText(R.string.login_failure);
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Send data from server to UserMainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserMainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("serverMessage", builder);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the return value to `errorMsg` for `doInBackground`. As it is more common practice. Tell me if this does or doesn't work.